# JOptionPane is not modal

Tags: java, modal-dialog, joptionpane, openoffice-writer

I have created a small Plugin for Open Office that can upload files directly. 
The Plugin returns the Following JOptionPane when a File was uploaded.

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Das Dokument wurde erfolgreich hochgeladen" ,"Success", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
```

Now when this pops up and the user klicks back in the OpenOffice Writer window the window jumps into the Background and freezes OpenOffice.

From all I know this has something to do with the modality of the window but the showMessageDialog(....) should always create a dialog that is modal and stays in the foreground.

How can I fix this issue or is there an other way to display this message as a modal Dialog ?